# How to make a library in SDP

Tags: programming-languages

How to make a libary in sdp? Sdp is the most simple programming language. Even there are `import` Keywords but there is no `export` Or `create import` Keywords. The only ones that can export data is the $DATA() function, the $GETD() function and the $SERVER() funcion.

And also there is no class keyword in SDP.

Answer (score 0):

Using SB files you can transfer data using $DATA. Imports also use $GETD function so how to make one? So first you have to mwke your sb file
And then import file.

```
Import file

var sb = new file(“data.sb”)
$DATA(“stuff”,sb)
```

Or you can use the xml.

```xml
<xml/>
<file x=“data.sb”/>
```

Or you can use LS library creation

```
Import ls

Export stuff from file(“data.sb”) to file(“main.sdp”){
 $Func stuff() {}
}
```